# SELECT COUNT(*) returns 0 when there is an AUTO INCREMENT field

Tags: mysql

I'll go to the point. I have the following table (MySQL 5.6.30)

```
CREATE TABLE `rankings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `group_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `rankings_user_id_index` (`user_id`),
  KEY `rankings_group_id_index` (`group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=100 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Now, in every test, I delete the records and insert new ones, so that

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM rankings WHERE user_id = 'hermione' and group_id = 'enchantments';
+-----+----------+--------------+
| id  | user_id  | group_id     |
+-----+----------+--------------+
| 122 | hermione | enchantments |
| 123 | hermione | enchantments |
+-----+----------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, the test fails when checking the total count (for pagination purposes, I only retrieve part of the records)

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM rankings WHERE user_id = 'hermione' and group_id = 'enchantments';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which is a very strange behavior... Digging a bit more, I've observed that:

- If I don't use an auto-increment field, everything works fine.
- If I insert a few more records manually, at some point the second query starts working as expected (caching issue?).

The `explain query` for the wrong and right results (in that order) is the following:

```
// WRONG
{
  select_type: SIMPLE,
  type: ref,
  possible_keys: rankings_user_id_index,rankings_group_id_index,
  key: rankings_user_id_index,
  ref: const,
  rows: 10
  extra: Using index condition; Using where
}


// RIGHT
{
  select_type: SIMPLE,
  type: index_merge,
  possible_keys: rankings_user_id_index,rankings_group_id_index,
  key: rankings_user_id_index,rankings_medgroup_id_index,
  ref: NULL,
  rows: 2
  extra: Using intersect(rankings_user_id_index,rankings_group_id_index); Using where; Using index
}
```

I do not understand the internals of MySQL, but I assume it tries to optimize the count in some way. However, it fails at that (at least in a test environment, where the table records are being deleted and recreated before every test case). Am I missing some cleaning step? Is MySQL's count caching expected to work this way?

Thank you

Comment: Can't reproduce it: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30e420/2 Are you using transactions?

Comment: @Barmar, I can't reproduce it either on sqlfiddle, but with a sequence of SQL queries I'm able to reproduce it in my local setup (a mysql:5.6 docker image with some custom configuration options). I suspect it might be the configuration, so I'll try to isolate the configuration option that makes it fail